# Can I use firebase phone number authentication in the server side (firebase js or firebase-admin)?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am always confuse while choosing between firebase js or firebase-admin. I wish to make endpoints to perform phone number authentication (one for sending OTP and another one to verify and doing some computations if the verification succeeds). Normally in the server side I should use firebase-admin but it doesn't provide a simple way as firebase js(on the client side) to perform that. My question is to know if I can use firebase js on my nodejs server api to perform that task?

```
/// Very simple way on the client side


import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";

const phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberFromUserInput();
const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

const auth = getAuth();
await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can use both SDKs but each one on its respective side. AdminSDK should always be used in NodeJS servers and FirebaseJS on client side.

In your case, as you're using phone authentication I suppose you're coding a ReactNative app so you should use [firebase RN phone auth](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth).

If you need to authenticate your user and send an SMS code to validate this authentication you can follow [this](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth#sign-in) section documentation as it is very ease to understand.

But if you want to retrieve your user data by it's phone number on your server you'll need to use firebase admin sdk. You can take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=pt-br#retrieve_user_data):

```
getAuth()
  .getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log(`Successfully fetched user data:  ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Hope this helps you :D

Comment: thanks, I found the solution using: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/verifying-phone-numbers-with-firebase-phone-authentication-on-your-backend-for-free-7a9bef326d02

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a way of doing it here. You can use link [user firebase phone number to verify otp](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/verifying-phone-numbers-with-firebase-phone-authentication-on-your-backend-for-free-7a9bef326d02). So you can use it to verify the opt and create the user with the firebase-admin sdk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).